logout isn't working properly in angular-auth-oidc-client
I'm using angular-auth-oidc-client to handle authentication proccess using microsoft identity provider
I want to log in app and use the token generated in another app without requiring login again, it works fine in login step but when i try to log out the list of accounts that shown in logout popup doesn't include the account I already signed in with.
when I debug I found the service
 this.oidcService.logoff().subscribe(res=>{
      this.accountService.logout();


})

isn't going to subscription
this is my config module
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AuthModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0',
        authWellknownEndpointUrl: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0',
        redirectUrl: `${window.location.origin}/complete`,
        clientId: "ddef7c5f-0fe0-4629-a8d4-7dea807f8711",
        scope: 'openid profile offline_access user.read',
        responseType: 'code',
        silentRenew: false,
        maxIdTokenIatOffsetAllowedInSeconds: 2800,
        issValidationOff: true,
        autoUserInfo: false,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: `${window.location.origin}/login`,
        silentRenewUrl: window.location.origin + '/silent-renew.html',
        useRefreshToken: true,
        logLevel: LogLevel.Debug,
        customParamsAuthRequest: {
          prompt: 'select_account', // login, consent
        },
        


      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: AbstractSecurityStorage, useClass: LocalStorageService }],
  exports: [AuthModule],
})

I'm not fully aware of how it works
Thanks in advance.

sounds like you are using an access token (session) on behalf of another user.  You're not really logged in with microsoft at that point until refresh token is exchanged.  (Each "app" will have it's own separate session if you login normally...)  Can you include how you are getting the token from the other "app"?
